# SQL-Duplicate 1 column multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql table with 3 columns and I want the third column NAME3
to be duplicated 100 times ie add 100 fields all similar to NAME3.

Note: Am not creating a new table, just altering existing table.

How do I do that?

Thanks

EDIT
Is there an auto way of doing it, without manually writing down each field?

Answer (score 0):

You would write out:

```
select col1, col2, name3, name3 as name4, name3 as name5, . . . , name3 as name100
```

You could put the code together in Excel, using Excel formulas.  The `as` gives each version a different name.

EDIT:

If you need to alter the table:

```
alter table t
    add name4 varchar(255),
        name5 varchar(255), 
        . . .
```

Then go in and do an `update`:

```
update t
    set name4 = name3,
        name5 = name3,
        . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to alter table, and not familiar with excel formulas, is there another way...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want 100 fields similar to name3 ?  Are they going to have same value as name3 ?

The reason I am asking .. you can solve this by creating view  if you don't need to persist those 100 fields.

If not you will need a script to generate alter table script .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They will have same values as NAME3, but values will change later. I need the fields persistent, looking for an sql script that does that.

Answer (score 0):

100 fields -- Probably you should have another table.  It would have a compound PRIMARY KEY:  The field(s) of the current PK, plus a TINYINT with values 1..100.